# Validation of viewstate MAC failed (adding machine key not working) - Gmail blocked sending emails

Tags: c#, gmail

Hello I am receiving this error in my program (ASP.NET 2):

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by
>   a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that  configuration
>   specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm.
>   AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

I used this [Machine Key generator](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/generatemachinekey) but the error still floods my email. Now I have a problem with my email provider (gmail). It blocked me from sending other emails.

How I can solve my two problems?

**web.config**

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <machineKey
  validationKey="00122301A2ED0E5D9908872E320484284FF6C7DBA469CEF9530B3AC47C6E8ED47E78CC6EFC92F42194BEFF724ED0FFEEA24C307E85056E5861B02925B737112E"
  decryptionKey="65DD387096C07101FDBC3A9E90450142568FE72F249A0DC40E8F8A456962F3B3"
  validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
```

Comment: Are you using a web farm or cluster?

Comment: How I can check that?

Comment: Can you add the code from your web.config where you have added the machine key.

Comment: Have you checked https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2915218/resolving-view-state-message-authentication-code-mac-errors ? What version of IIS are you running?

Comment: @mjwills Im working locally

Comment: When do you receive this error? more information the better.

Comment: When I run the application from Visual Studio

Comment: @TakoG so the first thing you see is this error message, you don't do a postback or anything?

Comment: @WooHoo In my application the first screen is login. So there is a postback. I cant check now because gmail is blocked again my sent mails...

Comment: @TakoG you have to provide these details up front to save time, it's taken several comments to find out you are running locally and the error appears when you login.

Comment: @WooHoo I know but its the first time I post here. I will keep in mind for later posts

Comment: @TakoG - is the page fully loading before logging in?  You can get this message if the page has not fully loaded and you postback.

Comment: @WooHoo no the page is fully loaded. I pulled the project from svn. other people using it they dont have problem